# Mercurial setup and firewall settings

Tags: mercurial, config, firewall, portforwarding

I'm trying to setup mercurial to work on a project with a few guys.

This is the situation:
I have a Debian64 server running, with hg installed and working. This is also a LAMP server.
My ISP blocks all ports <1023. For example, HTTP is redirected over port 8080 to circumvent this limitation.

How can I get these guys to push and pull from the mercurial server?
Portforwards and/or config settings that I need to set?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access a remote mercurial repository over `http`, `https`, or `ssh`. So as long as your server allows read/write access to the repository using one of those protocols you should be able to push to and pull from it.

I would recommend reading the mercurial wiki page on [Publishing Mercuiral Repositories](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/PublishingRepositories) for how to set up the repository on your server.. The easiest way is to use the `hgweb.cgi` script to access your repositories over `http` or `https`. To use it you copy the script to a directory where your Web server can access it. Then edit its contents so that it is reading the correct config file. Finally make sure the Web server (such as Apache) is configured and can execute the script. More detailed instructions are on the wiki page.

Comment: Also you can configure the port that Mercurial listens to using the `web.port` setting. E.g. `hg serve` by default listens on port 8000.